# What is the appropriate association for joining two unrelated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, `FlyerItem` and `Product`. If you think of a flyer for an electronics store it might show a TV on sale. For this particular case, I suppose that a flyer item advertises one product.

I've defined the model for the flyer item like this

```
class FlyerItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :product
end
```

The migration looks like this

```
class CreateFlyerItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :flyer_items, :primary_key => :flyer_item_id do |t|
      t.references :product
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my View I try to access a particular instance of an item like this

```
<% FlyerItem.find do |item| %>
  <p><%= item.product %></p>
<% end %>
```

However rails throws an exception

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column products.flyer_item_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."flye...
                                                    ^
: SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."flyer_item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "products"."product_id" ASC LIMIT
```

Which is expected, because a product really has nothing to do with a flyer item, so the Product table doesn't and shouldn't have that column.

What I really want to say is something like

SELECT * FROM flyer_items WHERE flyer_items.product_id = products.product_id

What kind of association would I use here?
Is an association even the correct approach?

A flyer must have one product, but a product does not necessarily need to be assigned to any flyers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `has_one` you want `belongs_to`. The `belongs_to` association method goes on the class that has the foreign key column. On the opposite side of the association you can use `has_many` or `has_one` depending on your needs.

```
class FlyerItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flyer_items
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess thinking about it in natural language doesn't really work in this case, as I'm thinking "well it doesn't really make sense for a product to have many flyer items"...but then these are relationships between tables, so I should remember to think of it that way.

Comment: It took me some time to get used to "language" aspect of it as well, but it does get easier. I found it helpful to think of the opposite relationship first, the one that does not contain a foreign key. In your case this is Product. A product "has many flyers" about it, one for all the holidays, and sales.

Comment: Your interpretation would be a more accurate representation of the relationship between a flyer item and a product. In that context, "has many" makes perfect sense.